# TypeScript override ToString()

Tags: javascript, typescript, overriding, tostring

Let's say I have a class `Person` which looks like this:

```
class Person {
    constructor(
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public age: number
    ) {}
}
```

I have overridden the `toString` method as follows.

```
public toString(): string {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
```

Now I expect to be able to do the following, which works in runtime:

```
function alertMessage(message: string) {
    alert(message);
}

alertMessage(new Person('John', 'Smith', 20));
```

But this still gives me this error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

How can I assign a `Person` to this `string` argument?

Comment: Have you tried your own example? seems to work already. https://jsfiddle.net/sy8wttvw/

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Overriding `toString` works kind of as expected:

```
class Foo {
    private id: number = 23423;
    public toString = () : string => {
        return `Foo (id: ${this.id})`;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   private name:string = "Some name"; 
   public toString = () : string => {
        return `Bar (${this.name})`;
    }
}

let a: Foo = new Foo();
// Calling log like this will not automatically invoke toString
console.log(a); // outputs: Foo { id: 23423, toString: [Function] }

// To string will be called when concatenating strings
console.log("" + a); // outputs: Foo (id: 23423)
console.log(`${a}`); // outputs: Foo (id: 23423)

// and for overridden toString in subclass..
let b: Bar = new Bar();
console.log(b); // outputs: Bar { id: 23423, toString: [Function], name: 'Some name' }
console.log("" + b); // outputs: Bar (Some name)
console.log(`${b}`); // outputs: Bar (Some name)

// This also works as expected; toString is run on Bar instance. 
let c: Foo = new Bar();
console.log(c); // outputs: Bar { id: 23423, toString: [Function], name: 'Some name' }
console.log("" + c); // outputs: Bar (Some name)
console.log(`${c}`); // outputs: Bar (Some name)
```

What can sometimes be an issue though is that it is not possible to access the `toString` of a parent class:

```
console.log("" + (new Bar() as Foo));
```

Will run the toString on Bar, not on Foo.

Comment: That kinda works for me, but getting more specific. I have a ts class like this `code` module Entidades  { 
export class eEpisodio{
public Id: numer} }`code`
If i try to use my toString() method adding some property, it doesn't work, it doesn't seem to find the Id property (or any at all)

Comment: I updated my answer. What might have been your problem is defining toString like a function. Defining it as a lambda property might work better (like i have done in my new more exhaustive example.)

Comment: @Nypan Is there a pro argument to use `public toString = () : string => {` instead of `public toString(): string {` ?

Comment: Yes, using `t() : =>` ensures that `this`will be what you expect in the toString override. You can read up on [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to learn more about this. But the basic difference here is that arrow functions does not bind their own this.

Answer (score 15):

As pointed out by @Kruga, the example actually seemed to work in runtime JavaScript. The only problem with this is that [TypeScript shows a type error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(firstName%3A%20string%2C%20lastName%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.firstName%20%3D%20firstName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.lastName%20%3D%20lastName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.age%20%3D%20age%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20toString()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.firstName%20%2B%20'%20'%20%2B%20this.lastName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20alertMessage(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(message)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AalertMessage(new%20Person('John'%2C%20'Smith'%2C%2020))%3B%0D%0A).

> **TS2345:** Argument of type 'Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

To resolve this message, you must either:

- Call `.toString()` explicitly
- Or concatenate the object with a string (e.g. `` `${obj}` `` or `obj + ''`)
- Or use `obj as any` (not recommended as you will lose type safety)

Comment: "concatenate the object with an empty string" worked for me

Comment: In that case explicit call to `toString()` seems more of a best-practice to me, when compared to the more 'hacky' concatenation with the empty string.